# I have some problems using the rpy2 package

Tags: python, rpy2

In this code, I cannot convert the variable cpgraph into the <class 'rpy2.robjects.vectors.IntMatrix'> type using ordinary robjects.r.matrix statements. Is it because my graph is more complicated?

here is the code

```
def sample_graphs(mpgraph, n_graphs=10, equal_weights=False):
    graphs = []
    if nx.is_directed_acyclic_graph(nx.DiGraph(mpgraph)):
        graphs.append((mpgraph.copy(), n_graphs))
    else:
        n_vars = mpgraph.shape[0]

        addBgKnowledge = robjects.r['addBgKnowledge']
        for _ in range(n_graphs):
            graph = mpgraph.copy()
            undirected_u, undirected_v = np.nonzero(np.triu(graph == graph.T) & (graph == 1))

            while len(undirected_u) > 0:
                selected_edge_idx = np.random.randint(0, len(undirected_u))
                u, v = undirected_u[selected_edge_idx], undirected_v[selected_edge_idx]
                if np.random.rand() < 0.5:
                    u, v = v, u

                numpy2ri.activate()
                pandas2ri.activate()

                cpgraph = robjects.r.matrix(graph, nrow=n_vars, ncol=n_vars)
                print(cpgraph)
                print(type(cpgraph))
                cpgraph.rownames = robjects.StrVector([str(i) for i in range(n_vars)])
                cpgraph.colnames = robjects.StrVector([str(i) for i in range(n_vars)])
                cpgraph = r_as(cpgraph, 'graphNEL')

                numpy2ri.deactivate()
                pandas2ri.deactivate()

                graph = r_as(addBgKnowledge(cpgraph, x=[str(u)], y=[str(v)]), 'matrix').astype(int)

                undirected_u, undirected_v = np.nonzero(np.triu(graph == graph.T) & (graph == 1))


            found = False

            for idx, (comp_graph, weight) in enumerate(graphs):
                if (comp_graph == graph).all():
                    graphs[idx] = (graph, weight + 1)
                    found = True
                    break

            if not found:
                graphs.append((graph, 1))

    if equal_weights:
        graphs = [(graph, 1 / len(graphs)) for graph, _ in graphs]
    else:
        graphs = [(graph, w / n_graphs) for graph, w in graphs]
    return graphs
```

I tried writing a separate piece of code to check the availability of the rpy2 package to prove that it is available.

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects import numpy2ri
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx

numpy2ri.activate()
data = np.array(\[1, 2, 3, 4\])
r_matrix = robjects.r.matrix(data, nrow=2, ncol=2)
print(type(r_matrix))

print(nx.__version__)
```

The output is：
<class 'rpy2.robjects.vectors.IntMatrix'>
2.5

Answer (score 0):

Using the `.activate()` methods is discouraged. Prefer a local converter (see [doc here](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.5.x/html/robjects_convert.html#local-conversion-rules)).

Beside that, what you must ensure is that your *Python* object `graph` can either be converted into an R sequence passed to the R function `matrix()` (see [doc here](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.5.x/html/vector.html#matrix)), or can directly be converted into an R matrix using rpy2's conversion rule sets (`numpy` matrix to R matrix is what `numpy2ri.converter` alone can do). `graph` appears to be a copy of `mpgraph` so that's the python type you'll have to look at.